# Declare table and join it shows slow, but fast when using real number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've try following SQL and it was slow when I useing declare `@NewCityJudge` table and join it, but it was fast when I convert table into real number and join it.

```
-- input id into @NewCityJudge, only one record
declare @NewCityJudge table(CountryId int)
insert into @NewCityJudge 
select CountryId from .... 


SELECT TOP (300) *
MyTable as b
    join ComponentLanguageIndex as c on c.id = b.[key]
    join ComponentCountryTags e on c.ComponentId = e.ComponentId
    join @NewCityJudge  as d on d.CountryId = e.CountryId -- join @NewCityJudge here
```

But it faster when using

```
SELECT TOP (300) *
MyTable  as b
    join ComponentLanguageIndex as c on c.id = b.[key]
    join ComponentCountryTags e on c.ComponentId = e.ComponentId
where CountryId in (39)
```

The `@NewCityJudge` always less 5 records.

The first way takes 5 seconds,
The second way takes 500 ms.

Thanks

PS. It was fast when using #NewCityJudge temp table, but I afraid it cause some transaction issue

[image]

Comment: did u try the indexing on CountryId?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed yes, it was take 36 ms when execute the select CountryId command

Comment: Are you saying that the first script including the create through to the select top 300 took 5 seconds or the select top 300 bit alone took 5 seconds?

Comment: @P.Salmon  first script including the create through to the select top 300 took 5 seconds

Comment: I'm not what your question is?  Are you asking why this is?  Or are you asking how you use a table var without suffering the performance hit?

Comment: How many countryid = 39 rows are created in the @NewJudgeCity table by insert?

Comment: @P.Salmon only 1 row

Comment: @destination-data how I use a table var without suffering the performance hit?

Comment: Can you add the execution plan?

Comment: I think your problem is that you are comparing 2 things completely different: one is a script with an insert and then a select statement, which take 5 seconds, and the other is a select statement that take 500ms... My advice would be compare just the 2 select statements to see how worst the first is compared to the second.

Comment: can't you directly use the country table for join instead of creating a table variable ? Are you using that table variable in multiple statements ?

Comment: @A-U, try `declare @NewCityJudge table(CountryId int PRIMARY KEY);`.  Note that table variables do not have statistics but the primary key declaration may better help the optimizer determine cardinality.

Comment: My porpose is to select rows where my CountryId is in @NewCityJudge, and the Country id is computed by FREETEXTTABLE function, so I can't predict the CountryId table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using temp table instead of parameter.

```
Create table  #NewCityJudge(CountryId int) insert into #NewCityJudge  select CountryId from .... 


SELECT TOP (300) * MyTable as b
    join ComponentLanguageIndex as c on c.id = b.[key]
    join ComponentCountryTags e on c.ComponentId = e.ComponentId
    join #NewCityJudge  as d on d.CountryId = e.CountryId
```

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to a Join, you could use the following:

```
SELECT TOP (300) *
MyTable  as b
    join ComponentLanguageIndex as c on c.id = b.[key]
    join ComponentCountryTags e on c.ComponentId = e.ComponentId
where e.CountryId IN (Select CountryId from @NewCityJudge)
```

Anytime you use TOP (#) on a table with some joins, it is less than ideal.   I would also like to understand why TOP (300) ?   Is this for testing purposes ?   How many records are in MyTable ?   If you remove TOP (300), you may find your query time issue resolved.

Comment: the statement you provide is still slow. I took top(300) is for testing purpose.